# How to add fill color between horizontal line and a plot?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How do I create a fill color between "the plot and a horizontal line" whenever the "plot" is above the "horizontal line"?

I can only seem to do it for plot and plot or hline and hline, but never both.

Example here I want to make the color filled between the ema 20 and the line, whenever ema is above 220.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

ema = ta.ema(close, 20)
hline = hline(220)

fill(hline, ema, color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. You cannot mix a `plot()` and an `hline()` in `fill()`.

As a workaround, you can just plot your hline.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

ema = ta.ema(close, 20)
p_ema = plot(ema)
p_hline = plot(220)

fill(p_hline, p_ema, color=color.red)
```